# plot a map with labels for city names in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a map with labels for city names. I know how to plot polygons from a shapefile but how do I label it with place names? Would these be in the shapefile or one of the other files included in the zipfile?

```
my_map = shaperead('myshapefile.shp');

Zone1 = rgb('Red');
Zone2 = rgb('Purple');
Zone3 = rgb('Orange');
Zone4 = rgb('Yellow');
Zone5 = rgb('SpringGreen');
Zone6 = rgb('DeepSkyBlue'); 

mapColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon',{'GRID_CODE',1,'Facecolor',Zone1,'FaceAlpha',0.5},...
    {'GRID_CODE',2,'Facecolor',Zone2,'FaceAlpha',0.5},{'GRID_CODE',3,'Facecolor',Zone3,'FaceAlpha',0.5},{'GRID_CODE',4,'Facecolor',Zone4},...
    {'GRID_CODE',5,'Facecolor',Zone5,'FaceAlpha',0.5},{'GRID_CODE',6,'Facecolor',Zone6,'FaceAlpha',0.5});

mapshow(my_map,'SymbolSpec',mapColors,my_labels);

axis off
```

Comment: Include your `.shp` file as well so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @rayryeng it's the shapefile from here http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/climate_averages/climate-classifications/index.jsp?maptype=tmp_zones#maps (temp/humidity zones) - thanks!

Comment: Also, why are the axes not in latitude/longitude? Is there a way to convert them so that I can plot coordinates?